# Не совсем понимаю что в с++ с множествами, конкретно с multiset

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Я добавляю в него например более 2-ух чисел то все впорядке, но если два числа то откуда то при вычислениях в множестве появляется третье число которое я не добавлял. Обьясните в чем дело?

[image]

```
multiset<double>mySet;
double res;
double temp;
int n, weight;
set<double>::reverse_iterator j = mySet.rbegin();

cin >> n;//Ввожу 2

for (int i = n; i > 0; i--) {
    cin >> weight;//Ввожу 72 и 50
    mySet.insert(weight);
}

copy(mySet.begin(), mySet.end(), ostream_iterator<double>(cout, " "));
res = 2 * (sqrt((*j - 1) * (*j)));//Вычисления с числами 71 и 72, откуда 71?
mySet.erase(*j);
mySet.erase(*j);
cout << res;
cout << endl;
copy(mySet.begin(), mySet.end(), ostream_iterator<double>(cout, " "));
```

Comment: Покажите код - без этого откуда же нам знать, что вы делаете неверно?...

Comment: Вроде бы все верно, но всеравно откуда то число 71

Comment: Дайте текст, а не картинку. Перенабирать и разбираться с картинкой - неудобно...

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> (*j - 1) * (*j)
> ```

Ну вообще-то 72-1 будет 71.

Comment: Точно, до меня только щяс дошло что это операция будет напрямую с числом а не с ссылкой..мдэ)

Comment: Исправил *j - 1 на *j++ и работает как нужно. Спасибо)

Comment: Сомнительно, что после этого работает как нужно.

Comment: Мне нужно было чтобы вычисление происходило на данном этапе с соседним элементом. И мое исправление сработало как нужно, можете проверить.